# What is the best way to do multiple submerses join in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have three sub-queries give me table a, b, c. I want to join them first, then select the necessary information. I am new to SQL, not sure if my joins are the best way:

Here is what I did so far

```
select
    a.truck,
    a.vendor,
    a.domicile,
    b.routes,
    c.status
from
    (select 
         Transp.truck
         Transp.vendor
         Transp.docimicle
     from
         Transp) a 
left join
    (select
         Dispatch.truck 
         count(Dispatch.routes) as routes
     from
         Dispatch
     group by
         Dispatch.truck) b on a.truck = b.truck
left join
    (select
         Repair.truck 
         Repair.status
     from
         Repair) c on a.truck = c.truck
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: thanks, i will pay attention

Comment: What are submerses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do away with at least two of the subqueries you currently have:

```
SELECT
    t.truck,
    t.vendor,
    t.domicile,
    COALESCE(b.routes, 0) AS routes,
    r.status
FROM Transp t
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT truck, COUNT(*) AS routes
    FROM Dispatch
    GROUP BY truck
) b
    ON t.truck = b.truck
LEFT JOIN Repair r
    ON t.truck = r.truck;
```

I said "at least" two of the subqueries, because it might also be possible to not use a subquery at all to compute the count.  But, I tend to prefer writing it as above, because it makes it explicit that you're doing an aggregation on the Dispatch table.

Comment: I simply my post, how about if I really need 3 sub-queries? is my way is ok?

Comment: Yes, the code looks fine, assuming you really need 3 subqueries.  But you should avoid them, because they preclude any chance of using an index which might exist on the table inside the subquery.  Translation: doing this may substantially slow down your query, so only do it if you really need to do it.